# mongodump ignore some specified collections

Tags: mongodb, mongodump

I was trying to backup my mongo database on the product sever.and then restore then back to the staging server.
and here comes some problem, there are a lot of collections in db, I want to igonre some collections that I don't want to restore on staging server.

I can approach this by dumpping the staging db, dumpping the producting db, and then restore the prodct to staging useing **--drop** option. and restore the specified collections in staging db. uh..it's really bad.

**1. dump producting db**

```
mongodump --host product-server-host --username abcd --password bcda -d db -o pruduct-dump-dir
```

**2. dump staging db**

```
mongodump --host staging-server-host --username abcd --password bcda -d db -o staging -dump-dir
```

**3. restore all collection, then restore the collection back**
restore pruduct-dump-dir to staging server

```
mongorestore --host staging-server-host --username abcd --password bcda --drop pruduct-dump-dir

mongorestore --host staging-server-host --username abcd --password bcda --drop --collection coll pruducting-dump-dir
```

Is there any option like ignore-collection when I'm dumpping?
any suggestion will be appreciated :3

Answer (score 107):

Now available from version 3.0.0

```
--excludeCollection <collection_name>
--excludeCollectionsWithPrefix <collection_prefix>
```

Repeat to exclude more than 1

Checkout [the documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/reference/program/mongodump/#cmdoption-mongodump-excludecollection)

Comment: Said documentation seems to give absolutely no indication of what it means by "array of strings". There isn't really a unified idea of arrays as parameters in the shell, so that could mean anything. Is it one string with comma separators? Is it any number of strings until a new flag is encountered? Are we supposed to put `()`s or `[]` around it? What about repeating the flag with a different collection? All of these are used as replacements for arrays, it'd be nice if someone could clarify what they actually want.

Comment: @Thor84no you are right, no indication what it means. But to exclude more than one collection you can repeat the excludeCollection parameter (I think this is what they mean with array). Example: `mongodump  --excludeCollection=users --excludeCollection=jobs -d mydatabase`

Comment: Finally I'm able to use the `--excludeCollection`! Thanks @DanielPérezRada

Answer (score 13):

```
mongodump --db test --excludeCollection=users --excludeCollection=salaries
```

Comment: would it be possible to add description to answer. I am not sure code only answers are good and stackoveflow standard.

Answer (score 9):

You can add `--collection COLLECTION_NAME` to dump the collection you need. By default, if you do not specify a collection to dump from a database, [MongoDump](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongodump/#cmdoption-mongodump--collection) will dump all collections in that database.

Comment: what if I have 20 collections need to dump except 4 collections

Comment: You'll need to dump each collection individually.

Comment: yeah something like `--exclude_collection col1 col2 col3` would be amazing. No mention of it in http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongodump/ . There appears to be a feature request in the MongoDB Jira: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-2459 you should vote for the issue

Answer (score 8):

As of Mongo 3.4, you can now specify an `--nsExclude <namespace pattern>` option when restoring from a Mongo database dump, which will exclude the specified namespaces from the restore operation. This is particularly useful when the `mongodump` operation has already occurred.

Official documentation here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/#cmdoption-nsexclude

You can exclude multiple collections with wildcards:

```
mongorestore --db test --nsExclude 'test.*_tmp'
```

Or alternatively, specifying multiple `--nsExclude` options work as well:

```
mongorestore --db test --nsExclude 'test.collection1' --nsExclude 'test.collection2'
```

Comment: You can use --nsInclude as well instead of --db mongorestore --nsInclude test --nsExclude 'test.collection1' --nsExclude 'test.collection2'

Answer (score 0):

I had to do the same while backing up a mongo db. If you use python (or any other language), you can use similar approach as well. After doing the mongodump, you simple have to remove the unwanted collection's bson & the metadata.json files.

```
    import os
    EXCLUDE_COLLECTIONS = ['collection_1', 'collection_2']
    db_dump_path = "/Path/to/mongodump"
    db_name = "name_of_db"
    for collection_name in EXCLUDE_COLLECTIONS:
        bson_file_path = os.path.join(db_dump_path, db_name, '{}.bson'.format(collection_name)
        meta_file_path = os.path.join(db_dump_path, db_name, '{}.metadata.json'.format(collection_name)
        if os.path.exists(bson_file_path) and os.path.exists(meta_file_path):
            os.remove(bson_file_path)
            os.remove(meta_file_path)
```